# How to calculate uptime in an Azure Functions App?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions

As part of my health check endpoint, I want to include the uptime for the queried Azure Function App. How can I determine when the instance of the function app was started?

Answer (score 0):

Add a static property on the Startup.cs class.

```
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public static readonly DateTimeOffset ApplicationStartDateTimeUtc =
            DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
...
```

```
        [FunctionName("StatusApi")]
        [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "GetStatus", tags: new[] { "status" })]
        [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "text/plain", bodyType: typeof(StatusResponse), Description = "The OK response")]
        public IActionResult GetStatus(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "status")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(GetStatus)} endpoint triggered.");

            return new OkObjectResult(new StatusResponse(
                version: GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version!.ToString(),
                upTime: (DateTimeOffset.UtcNow - Startup.ApplicationStartDateTimeUtc).ToString()));
        }
```